# Cordova sockets send Unicode

Tags: javascript, cordova, sockets, powerbuilder

I have a legacy windows TCP server which we cannot touch, it's built using Powerbuilder 10.5 (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37774.1252/html/apptech/apptech_unicodesupport.htm) 
, which according to Sybase link above, expects unicode strings (UTF-16LE) and needed a small mobile app which sends a simple string to this server.

Discovered Cordova and the plugin https://github.com/kitolog/sockets-for-cordova
Built a demo application but it only works with ANSI.

This is the example code from the plugin homepage

```
var dataString = "Hello world";
var data = new Uint8Array(dataString.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = dataString.charCodeAt(i);
}
socket.write(data);
```

For debugging purposes only, the server has an option to receive ANSI. We enabled this option and the Cordova app works fine.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [UTF-8 to UTF-16LE Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379446/utf-8-to-utf-16le-javascript) , the solution is:

```
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(text.length * 2);
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    byteArray[i*2] = text.charCodeAt(i) // & 0xff;
    byteArray[i*2+1] = text.charCodeAt(i) >> 8 // & 0xff;
}
```