# Converting UTF-8 data to UTF-16 with BOM

Tags: javascript, csv, utf-8, utf-16

I have a variable called `csv` and it contains all the data I require. I want to convert this data to `UTF-16LE` as I want Excel to recognize the data by just opening the file, without the need of the `Get Data` button.

I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24386744), and while LibreOffice Calc does recognize it is a `UTF-16` file, Excel does not decode the greek characters correctly.

Here is the JavaScript code I have:

```js
csv = csvRows.join('\r\n')

      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(csv.length * 2);
      for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i * 2] = csv.charCodeAt(i) // & 0xff;
        byteArray[i * 2 + 1] = csv.charCodeAt(i) >> 8 // & 0xff;
      }

      var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'text/csv', encoding: "UTF-16LE" });
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      sendFileToClient(url, this.el.id + ".csv")
```

A similar problem I had in Elixir I solved by using the `:unicode` module like so:

```el
csv =
      :unicode.characters_to_binary(
        :unicode.encoding_to_bom(:utf8) <> build_csv(data),
        :utf8,
        {:utf16, :little}
      )
```

I tried also adding a `\uFEFF` BOM character at the beginning of the file but that makes it so its recognized as `UTF-8 BOM` file (according to Notepad++). When I tried `\uFFFE` which is the `UTF-BOM character was turned into different letters.

[LibreOffice Calc opening the file without BOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uHEl.png)

[LibreOffice Calc opening the file with `\ufeff` BOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqo84.png)

[Excel opening the file without BOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAzR2.png)

[Excel opening the file with BOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK3VT.png)

Comment: Note: Excel can read without problems UTF-8 files. So it is possible that the problem is not about encoding. Common problems: separator. CSV usually use comma, but on many locales Excel expect by default other characters. (with a special first line, you can set the separator, but then the file is one line with own format + all rest as CSV data. Or the thousand separator in numbers, or decimal point. Check in a text editor. Try with just simple integers (to remove most variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the UTF-8 BOM before converting the content to UTF-16.